# Difference between System.out and Printstream

Tags: java

Is there any difference in these statements

```
System.out.println(error);
```

AND

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream((OutputStream)System.out);
ps.println(error);
```

Comment: Not sure why this was marked down, as it seems a reasonable question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.out` is already a `PrintStream`,

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream((OutputStream)(System.out));
```

would only wrap it once more which seems pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there is no difference. The second way is too prolonged. out is a static field of type java.io.PrintStream in System class. You could directly use it instead of casting it to Outputstream and again wrapping it inside another PrintStream reference. They both are going to use the same underlying PrintStream object regardless.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference except for the fact that you made a copy of `out`.

From [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

> out
>
> > public static final PrintStream out

It is already of type `PrintStream`.