# Assigning PrintStream reference as System.out

Tags: java

What is the deference between below 2 ways of printing values.

1)

```
PrintStream out = System.out;
out.println("hi");
```

2)

```
System.out.println("hi");
```

Do I need to close "out" in case 1??

Comment: i think this question is already answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726323/difference-between-system-out-and-printstream

Comment: proposed duplicate is slightly different. That one is making a copy/wrapper, whereas here there is no copy created.

Comment: All you did in the first case is assign an intermediate variable. Which is valid, just somewhat pointless

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. No, you don't need to close "out" in case 1.

If you would close it, you would no longer have access to standard output stream, which is generally not a situation you want.