# Is there any difference between printing statements using PrintStream object and System.out.println() in Java?

Tags: java

I have printed the data by using PrintStream object as below.

PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
ps.println("Printing");

And I have also printed the data using System.out.println();
System.out.println(("Printing"));

I see no difference between these two statements. Do anyone clarify about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between System.out and Printstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726323/difference-between-system-out-and-printstream)

Comment: What’s the point of creating a `PrintStream` wrapping another `PrintStream`?

Answer (score 1):

In your example it would work in a similar way, but `System.out.println("")` is generally used as an easy way to log to the console, while the `new PrintStream()` could also be used to redirect to a different stream, such as a remote endpoint. Generally the `System.out.println` is the more commonly used way to print things to the console.

Btw, you can actually redirect the System.out to something else by using the `System.setOut(stream)`, so you wouldn't lose flexibility if you would `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 1):

> *I see no difference between these two statements.*

I agree, functionally they're the same.

[`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) returns a `PrintStream`, so this is fine:

```
PrintStream out = System.out;
out.println("Printing");
```

Creating a new `PrintStream` using the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream-java.io.OutputStream-) where you pass in an `OutputStream` – as you did with this: `new PrintStream(System.out)` – will create a new `PrintStream` object wrapped around the constructor argument.

So when you did the code below, you're simply putting a wrapper around the same underlying output stream.

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
ps.println("Printing");
```

Either way, when you call `println("Printing")`, it's resolving to the same [`println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-) method.